# C# Reading CSV data with correct cell format using Regex

Tags: c#, csv, number-formatting

C# Reading CSV data with correct cell format using Regex.

I am facing issue with CSV cell format.

My excel data is as below:

```
Date      |    Acct    |  Name
20210928  |  3.02+ 13  | ABC
```

where Acct is 14 digit number. But Acct number is displayed as in above format.

Code for reading excel data is as below:

```
var csvlines = File.ReadAllLines(file);
Regex CSVParser = new Regex(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*(?![^\"]*\"))");
var csvLinesData = csvlines.Skip(1).Select(l => CSVParser.Split(l).ToArray());
```

With this code, CSV comma separated cells value will be added in Array.
But here for Acct field data is getting fetched as "3.02+ 13"  but I need it as 14 digit number

How can I do that in above code? any thing to do with Regex?

Comment: Before you attempt to write your own CSV parser, investigate whether any of the existing free CSV parsing packages available on NuGet solve this problem. There's no need to reinveint the wheel.

Comment: The content *is* `3.02+ 13`. What you ask is to parse that string into a number, which can't be done with regex. You'll have to use `long.Parse`

Comment: You mean the data is presented like that _when you import it into a spreadsheet editor_? Or when you look at the raw data written to the file?

Comment: This is because Excel converted your 14 digit number to "scientific notation" which is unfortunately a common issue.  See https://www.logicbroker.com/excel-scientific-notation-disable-prevent/.  Your parsing isn't the issue the issue is that the CSV file itself has already been corrupted.

Comment: I can't imagine many cases where I'd use regex to parse CSV. I'd use CsvHelper (available in NuGet). Regex is not the hammer to use on every nail.

Answer (score 0):

My CSV parser ([CsvParser](https://github.com/SoftCircuits/CsvParser)) will parse the values in a CSV file for you.

In your example, that value appears to be non-standard. However, my library allows you to write your own custom converter for just that one column. It shouldn't be too hard to convert that value with a little custom code.

There are examples of how to write a custom converter class on my GitHub page.